# Constraint issues in Xcode 9.0

Tags: ios, uiview, constraints

I have a very simple app with just a UIView and a Button. I have added the constraints, so that the UIView fits the whole screen with a 10px margin. However, when running the app on different devices, it seems these constraints aren't heeded at all, instead my UIView has a fixed size... The button does behave as expected.
Here are my constraints: [image: Constraints]

And here it how it looks on different devices: [image: iPadAir], [image: iPhone8], [image: iPhoneSE]

I realize that this is a very basic question. But I have built other apps and never had any issues with the constraints...

My Deoplyment Info is:
Deployment Target: 8.0
Devices: Universal:
Device Orientation: Landscape Left/ Landscape Right
Satus Bar Style: Default and Requires Full Screen

EDIT:
Here is a screenshot of my view-hierarchy in the main storyboard: [image]

Comment: could you share a screenshot of your storyboard outline (view hierarchy) ?